# How to change name in CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS python

Tags: python, mysql

Hi i want to insert a table name and create the table only if it doesn't exist.

My code

```
name = raw_input('tablename :')
query.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS '"+ name +"'(`id` int())")
```

After that i got

```
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''table1'(`id` int())' at line 1")
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes around table name:

```
query.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+ name +" (`id` int)")
```

or use backticks (`) if it clashes with a reserved name:

```
query.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `"+ name +"` (`id` int)")
```

Comment: Wrong syntax again .Time time i got `'_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '123(`id` int())' at line 1")'`

Comment: What is 123? If you want to name your tables consisting of numbers only, you should use the backticks method. See the second example in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `int()` and the quotes. Do this way:

`query.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+ name +"(id INT)")`